# How to catch any error show up in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception, event-handling

So i have a task to make a project like larabug.it will catch any error and store this error to database. but i have no idea how to catch this error?
or give me some references
i have stuck for a days

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is described in detail in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#reporting-exceptions).

Comment: ofcourse, but can i make it globally?
i mean everytime the project has an error it will catch by one function or controller.

Comment: register function in App\Exceptions\Handler.php will do the trick